Can discrete time random processes be a finite collection of random variables?
1)Assuming a discrete time random process, can the random process have a finite number of random variables?
2)it seems like to me that “time series” often refers to discrete time random processes(and in other times  a sample path of one); and realistically its a finite number of random variables.

The answer to the first question an the title is yes. A time series is usually understood as a collection of histrorical data. Apart from that your second question is purely linguistic having zero mathematical content.
